# OPCUA Java milo Structure in Structure Error in UAExpert

Tags: java, opc-ua, milo

I'm using milo 0.5.4 to setup my own OpCUA server.

Now I try to use a complex Datatype which should include a structure inside a structure.

But when connecting to UAExpert client, following error message is shown:

UaBsdReader::evaluateTypeName: Could not determine data type of TypeName ua: Structure

BsdReader could not interpret type ua:Structure in field status

Below i added a picture of UAExpert result

i guess the problem has to do with Identifiers.Structure in registerToxStructType(). But i do not know what else should be used here.
I hope anyone out there could give me a hint?

```
new StructureField("status", LocalizedText.NULL_VALUE, Identifiers.Structure, ValueRanks.Scalar, null, uint(0), false) };
```

This is my first structure registration:

```
    private void registerStatusStructType() throws Exception {
        // Get the NodeId for the DataType and encoding Nodes.

        NodeId dataTypeId = StatusStructType.TYPE_ID.toNodeIdOrThrow(getServer().getNamespaceTable());

        NodeId binaryEncodingId = StatusStructType.BINARY_ENCODING_ID.toNodeIdOrThrow(getServer().getNamespaceTable());
        
        dictionaryManager.registerStructureCodec(new StatusStructType.Codec(), "StatusStructType", dataTypeId, binaryEncodingId ); ///, parentTypeId);
        

        StructureField[] fields = new StructureField[] { new StructureField("type",   LocalizedText.NULL_VALUE, Identifiers.String, ValueRanks.Scalar, null, uint(0), false), 
                                                         new StructureField("text",   LocalizedText.NULL_VALUE, Identifiers.String, ValueRanks.Scalar, null, uint(0), false), 
                                                         new StructureField("source", LocalizedText.NULL_VALUE, Identifiers.String, ValueRanks.Scalar, null, uint(0), false) };

        StructureDefinition definition = new StructureDefinition(binaryEncodingId, Identifiers.Structure, StructureType.Structure, fields);

        StructureDescription description = new StructureDescription(dataTypeId, new QualifiedName(getNamespaceIndex(), "StatusStructType"), definition);

        dictionaryManager.registerStructureDescription(description, binaryEncodingId);

    }
```

This is the registration of the structure where i want to include the first one:

```
    private void registerToxStructType() throws Exception {
        // Get the NodeId for the DataType and encoding Nodes.

        NodeId dataTypeId = ToxStructType.TYPE_ID.toNodeIdOrThrow(getServer().getNamespaceTable());

        NodeId binaryEncodingId = ToxStructType.BINARY_ENCODING_ID.toNodeIdOrThrow(getServer().getNamespaceTable());

        dictionaryManager.registerStructureCodec(new ToxStructType.Codec(), "ToxStructType", dataTypeId, binaryEncodingId);
        
        StructureField[] fields = new StructureField[] { 
                new StructureField("foo",    LocalizedText.NULL_VALUE, Identifiers.String,    ValueRanks.Scalar, null, getServer().getConfig().getLimits().getMaxStringLength(), false), 
                new StructureField("bar",    LocalizedText.NULL_VALUE, Identifiers.Int32,     ValueRanks.Scalar, null, uint(0), false), 
                new StructureField("baz",    LocalizedText.NULL_VALUE, Identifiers.Boolean,   ValueRanks.Scalar, null, uint(0), false),  //};
                new StructureField("status", LocalizedText.NULL_VALUE, Identifiers.Structure, ValueRanks.Scalar, null, uint(0), false) };

        StructureDefinition definition = new StructureDefinition(binaryEncodingId, Identifiers.Structure, StructureType.Structure, fields);

        StructureDescription description = new StructureDescription(dataTypeId, new QualifiedName(getNamespaceIndex(), "ToxStructType"), definition);

        dictionaryManager.registerStructureDescription(description, binaryEncodingId);
    }
```

This is the function to add ToxStructType

```
    private void addToxStructTypeVariable(UaFolderNode rootFolder) throws Exception {
        NodeId dataTypeId = ToxStructType.TYPE_ID.toNodeIdOrThrow(getServer().getNamespaceTable());

        NodeId binaryEncodingId = ToxStructType.BINARY_ENCODING_ID.toNodeIdOrThrow(getServer().getNamespaceTable());

        UaVariableNode ToxStructTypeVariable = UaVariableNode.builder(getNodeContext())
                                                             .setNodeId(newNodeId("ThisIsMyPart/ToxStructTypeVariable"))
                                                             .setAccessLevel(AccessLevel.READ_WRITE)
                                                             .setUserAccessLevel(AccessLevel.READ_WRITE)
                                                             .setBrowseName(newQualifiedName("ToxStructTypeVariable"))
                                                             .setDisplayName(LocalizedText.english("ToxStructTypeVariable"))
                                                             .setDataType(dataTypeId)
                                                             .setTypeDefinition(Identifiers.BaseDataVariableType)
                                                             .build();
        
        StatusStructType statestruct = new StatusStructType("Error 0010", "Error 0010 occured! 0x0F", "Device 0010?");

        ToxStructType value = new ToxStructType("foo", 42, true, statestruct );

        ExtensionObject xo = ExtensionObject.encodeDefaultBinary(getServer().getSerializationContext(), value, binaryEncodingId);

        ToxStructTypeVariable.setValue(new DataValue(new Variant(xo)));

        getNodeManager().addNode(ToxStructTypeVariable);

        ToxStructTypeVariable.addReference(new Reference(ToxStructTypeVariable.getNodeId(), Identifiers.Organizes, rootFolder.getNodeId().expanded(), false));
    }
```

Structure ToxStructType.java:

```
package com.toxware.export.opcua.communication.server.util;

import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.UaSerializationException;
import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.serialization.OpcUaBinaryStreamDecoder;
import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.serialization.OpcUaBinaryStreamEncoder;
import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.serialization.SerializationContext;
import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.serialization.UaStructure;
import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.serialization.codecs.OpcUaBinaryDataTypeCodec;
import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.builtin.ExpandedNodeId;

import com.toxware.export.opcua.communication.server.ToxNamespaceDRX;

public class ToxStructType implements UaStructure {

    public static final ExpandedNodeId TYPE_ID = ExpandedNodeId.parse(String.format("nsu=%s;s=%s", ToxNamespaceDRX.NAMESPACE_URI, "DataType.ToxStructType"));

    public static final ExpandedNodeId BINARY_ENCODING_ID = ExpandedNodeId.parse(String.format("nsu=%s;s=%s", ToxNamespaceDRX.NAMESPACE_URI, "DataType.ToxStructType.BinaryEncoding"));

    private final String foo;
    private final Integer bar;
    private final boolean baz;
    private final StatusStructType status;

    @Override
    public ExpandedNodeId getTypeId() {
        return TYPE_ID;
    }

    public ToxStructType(String foo, Integer bar, boolean baz, StatusStructType status) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
        this.baz = baz;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public ToxStructType() {
        this(null, 0, false, new StatusStructType());
    }

    public static class Codec implements OpcUaBinaryDataTypeCodec<ToxStructType> {
        @Override
        public Class<ToxStructType> getType() {
            return ToxStructType.class;
        }

        @Override
        public ToxStructType decode(SerializationContext context, OpcUaBinaryStreamDecoder reader) throws UaSerializationException {
            String foo = reader.readString("foo");
            Integer bar = reader.readInt32("bar");
            boolean baz = reader.readBoolean("baz");
            Object statusStruct = reader.readStruct("status", new StatusStructType.Codec());
            StatusStructType statusStructure = new StatusStructType();
            if (statusStruct.getClass().isAssignableFrom(StatusStructType.class)) {
                statusStructure = (StatusStructType) statusStruct;
            }
            return new ToxStructType(foo, bar, baz, statusStructure);
        }

        @Override
        public void encode(SerializationContext context, OpcUaBinaryStreamEncoder writer, ToxStructType value) throws UaSerializationException {
            writer.writeString("foo", value.foo);
            writer.writeInt32("bar", value.bar);
            writer.writeBoolean("baz", value.baz);
            writer.writeStruct("status", value.status, StatusStructType.TYPE_ID);
        }
    }

}
```

StatusStructType.java:

```
package com.toxware.export.opcua.communication.server.util;

import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.UaSerializationException;
import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.serialization.OpcUaBinaryStreamDecoder;
import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.serialization.OpcUaBinaryStreamEncoder;
import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.serialization.SerializationContext;
import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.serialization.UaStructure;
import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.serialization.codecs.OpcUaBinaryDataTypeCodec;
import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.builtin.ExpandedNodeId;

import com.toxware.export.opcua.communication.server.ToxNamespaceDRX;

public class StatusStructType implements UaStructure {

    public static final ExpandedNodeId TYPE_ID = ExpandedNodeId.parse(String.format("nsu=%s;s=%s", ToxNamespaceDRX.NAMESPACE_URI, "DataType.StatusStructType"));

    public static final ExpandedNodeId BINARY_ENCODING_ID = ExpandedNodeId.parse(String.format("nsu=%s;s=%s", ToxNamespaceDRX.NAMESPACE_URI, "DataType.StatusStructType.BinaryEncoding"));

    String type = "txt_0";
    String text = "txt_1";
    String source = "txt_2";

    @Override
    public ExpandedNodeId getTypeId() {
        return TYPE_ID;
    }

    public StatusStructType(String type, String text, String source) {
        this.type = type;
        this.text = text;
        this.source = source;

    }

    public StatusStructType() {
        this("", "", "");
    }

    public static class Codec implements OpcUaBinaryDataTypeCodec<StatusStructType> {
        @Override
        public Class<StatusStructType> getType() {
            return StatusStructType.class;
        }

        @Override
        public StatusStructType decode(SerializationContext context, OpcUaBinaryStreamDecoder reader) throws UaSerializationException {
            String type = reader.readString("type");
            String text = reader.readString("text");
            String source = reader.readString("source");
            return new StatusStructType(type, text, source);
        }

        @Override
        public void encode(SerializationContext context, OpcUaBinaryStreamEncoder writer, StatusStructType value) throws UaSerializationException {
            writer.writeString("type", value.type);
            writer.writeString("text", value.text);
            writer.writeString("source", value.source);
        }
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

}
```

[UAExpert Result / ErrorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRhUE.png)

Answer (score 0):

> i guess the problem has to do with Identifiers.Structure in registerToxStructType(). But i do not know what else should be used here. I hope anyone out there could give me a hint?

You should use the NodeId that identifies the StatusStructType (`StatusStructType.TYPE_ID`).

I don’t know if this will fix your issue entirely but it’s a good first step.

Comment: Hello Kevin, thanks for your quick anser. Could you tell me where i have to use StatusStrcutType.TYPE_ID ?

Comment: Where you are describing the “status” field of the “Tox” structure. The DataType of that field is not Identifiers.Structure, it’s whatever NodeId you’ve assigned to the StatusStructType to identify its DataType.

Comment: in function registerToxStructType() in definition of StructureField[] fields i replaced identifiers.structure by StatusStructType.TYPE_ID.toNodeIdOrThrow(getServer().getNamespaceTable())

Answer (score 0):

Now it works. The solution was:
in function registerToxStructType() in definition of StructureField[] fields i had to replac
identifiers.structure
by
StatusStructType.TYPE_ID.toNodeIdOrThrow(getServer().getNamespaceTable())